# Render image using OutputStream In FOP

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I wanted to render image on PDF which is going to generated by FOP. To render image I am using tag `<fo:external-graphic>` As below :

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('../offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8')" inline-progression-dimension.maximum="100%"  content-height="scale-down-to-fit" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"> </fo:external-graphic>
```

I also tried by giving full URL as:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="http://10.2.10.79/Web/offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=e391d672-ebf4-44d8-86cb-2cf987a50bf7" inline-progression-dimension.maximum="100%"  content-height="scale-down-to-fit" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"> </fo:external-graphic>
```

In controller I am having an request mapping `(../offlinePaper/displayImage)` which takes image name `disImg` from `getParameter` and decrypt the image and return in `OutputStream`.

But when I generate PDF I found Error in log file as:

```
Image not available. URI: http://10.2.10.79:80/Web/offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for http://10.2.10.79:80/Web/offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8 (No context info available)
```

But if I copy this URL and paste in URL then image get shown in browser and I also found that when I generate PDF the request mapping which is suppose to get call for image decryption is not getting called.

**Update**

***Also a strange think I come to know that with same code PDF get successfully generated if web server is `Tomcat` but if I deploy application on `Glassfish` it's giving error.***

Comment: I have a similar problem only for images generated by jsp and i use Outputstream too. Did you only changed the web server or have you made other chages in the code?
This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768480/image-not-displayed-on-pdf

Comment: @FernandoPrieto, no I just changed server. currently I solved this by writing `URIResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

In the exception trace stands:

> ImageException: The file format is not supported

The FO seems to be able to find an `ImagePreloader` according to file extension. If it doesn't find any, it breaks.

I'd propose to change the way how the url is built. There should be a real image file name included.

So, instead of:

> ../offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8

try

> ../offlinePaper/displayImage/disImg4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8.jpg

Comment: I can't do this. because I am having images which is encrypted so I have to decrypt the image first that's why I am doing like this, Read More @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347812/java-load-image-from-database-as-the-byte-stream-and-load-it-in-xsl

Comment: how about `../offlinePaper/displayImage.jpg?disImg=4bec89f0-5b97-40c3-b7c9-ac555a664df8`?

Comment: Will try and get back to you in few minutes.

Comment: No, Still the same error I got. I put an `sysout` in controller (/offlinePaper/displayImage.jpg) requestMapping part where image get decrypted I can't see that sysout in console. This means FOP engine is not able to call request mapping also. :(

Comment: What if you set content-type (if you know what it is)? The fo:external-graphic tag takes a content-type attribute with the mimetype expected.

Comment: are you using relative of absolute urls? as I can remember, relative one are more error-prone for FO

Comment: @KevinBrown, Yes i added `content-type="content-type:image/jpeg"` stilll its giving the same. Actually problem is i given src as `http://10.2.10.79/Web/offlinePaper/displayImage?disImg=e391d672-ebf4-44d8-86cb-2cf987a50bf7` so it suppose to call `RequestMapping` /offlinePaper/displayImage with image id but i put `sysout` in controller its not getting printed on console.