# Image not displayed on pdf

Tags: java, image, jsp, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I'm trying to include an image into a pdf which is generated via `XSL` using Apache Cocoon. I've read about the tag `<fo:external-graphic>` which works fine when a image is stored on the local drive or when you request an image which resides physically on any server. But what I need is to show in the pdf an image (codebar image) which is generated dynamically by a `jsp`, that is to say, `java` generates the image and it will never be stored on the hard drive.

The image is generated correctly by the jsp since it is showed on my browser. The problem is that the image is not shown in the `pdf` there is only big white space instead of the codebar image.

That is, something like these works fine:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="http://website.com/codebar.jpg" content-width="3cm" content-height="3cm"></fo:external-graphic>

<fo:external-graphic src="c:\Archivos de Programa\codebar.jpg" content-width="3cm" content-height="3cm"></fo:external-graphic>
```

But what I need to work is this:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="http://website.com/codebarGenerator.jsp" content-width="3cm" content-height="3cm"></fo:external-graphic>
```

The response headers are set correctly:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
```

**EDIT**

I think the problem, may be, is that I'm trying to insert `html` instead of an `image` and that is why the pdf does not display the image. But, how can I get only the image generated by `http://website.com/codebarGenerator.jsp` without storing it in the hard drive?

Comment: Are you sure you have all the parameters on the JSP? As in ... does that JSP just return some canned or random barcode or are you missing the parameters that actually generate the specific barcode in question? If you are not sending all the information, it could of course return nothing and you get nothing.

Comment: Yes, actually the jsp generates a specific barcode, just for testing so it doesn´t need any parameters. As i described above http://website.com/codebarGenerator.jsp shows the barcode image on the browser correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue I posted about this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511859/render-image-using-outputstream-in-fop). I solved this by using `URIResolver`.

You can try for this also:

```
public class PdfURIResolver implements URIResolver{
@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
    Source source = null;       
    try 
    {       
        //Image to InputStream conversion code here,
       //assign that InputStream to 'source' using source = new StreamSource(InputStream );         

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //exception handling
    }
    finally
    {
        //resourse closing if needed.
    }
    return source;
}
}
```

You have to tell FOP factory to use this Resolver using `fopFactory.setURIResolver(new PdfURIResolver());`