# How to read an image from a database and display it in xslt?

Tags: java, xsl-fo

I have a `jpeg` image of a signature stored in a database which I want to insert into a `pdf` file generated with xsl-fo.  I know I can insert an image with a url with

```
                            <fo:external-graphic src="url('theme/DNRLogo.gif')" width="0.85cm"/>
```

I know I can store values from my java objects in a handler and display them using

```
    <fo:table-cell padding-left="0.1cm" number-columns-spanned="7" border-left="0.50pt solid black" border-right="0.50pt solid black" border-bottom="0.50pt solid black" >
            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="shipperCity"/><fo:leader /></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
```

My question is can I store a `jpeg` image from the database into a java object and display it or do I have to use a different technique?  Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have the image stored in a java byte array.  I am using the `element(String,String)` method in `Apache's` `EasyGenerationContentHandlerProxy` to convert my java object fields to `xsl-fo` fields.  Is there a way to convert the byte array into something the `xsl-fo` can display as an image?

Comment: What FO formatter are you using and how are you invoking it?  What URI are you going to put in `fo:external-graphic/@src` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#src) to access the image in the database?

Comment: I am using `Apache's` `FopXml2Pdf` code which uses `Apache's` `AbstractObjectReader` and `EasyGenerationContentHandlerProxy`.  I don't know how to use an `URI` to access the data base.  I have the image stored in a byte array.  Is there a way to display that as in image using the xsl-fo?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347812/java-load-image-from-database-as-the-byte-stream-and-load-it-in-xsl